# No Styling When Using @PathVariable??? SpringBoot MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, get

got an odd one here that I can't figure out. I got a controller that is supposed to transfer search results from the business layer to the view.

My first approach was this:

```
@GetMapping("/path/{searchTerm}")
public String request1(@PathVariable(value = "searchTerm") String searchTerm, Model model) { 
    List<Result> results = searchService.getResults(searchTerm);
    model.addAttribute("reports", results);
    return "searchresults";
}
```

everything works, except that the result page has no styling when viewed in the browser. I tries multiple things to fix it but can't figure out why.

Then I tried this, which I think is supposed to be the same thing:

```
@GetMapping("/path")
public String request2(@RequestParam(value="searchTerm", required = false) String searchTerm, Model model) { 
    List<Result> results = searchService.getResults(searchTerm);
    model.addAttribute("reports", results);
    return "searchresults";
}
```

And sure enough, with @RequestParam it works and I have styling.

I just can't let of the problem, because I thought they were supposed to be identical solutions. It's bugging me why the @PathVariable version doesn't work.

Please help me put my mind at ease and tell me what I'm doing wrong in the first version with @PathVariable.

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably using a relative path to link to your CSS file. Suppose you use `style.css`. In the working case, it will be loaded from /style.css. In the second case, it will be loaded from /path/style.css.

Comment: that could be it - how do I fix this?

Comment: By using an absolute path, or a correct relative path.

Comment: You are correct. Issue solved. Thanks!